# How to properly call C++ function in multi threaded design?

Tags: c++, dll

I have this code:

```
void CMyComponent::ProcessData(std::string ss){
  // do stuff with data, its could take a long while
}
```

Now I want to call this ProcessData() method from this

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyComponent::WriteData(BSTR data, BSTR* retstr){
  std::string ss = _bstr_t(data, false);
  // Question: How to properly call ProcessData and send the std::string to the multithreaded app
}
```

The primary goal is that the WriteData will be called but will return immediately as the ProcessData() will run in the background.

Comment: Take a look at the [thread documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11 added a big support for multithreading, so I suggest you use it.

You can set this up using threads as said in the comments. Another way could be using [future](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)s and [promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)s if you want to send back easily results.

A future allows to defer a computation to another thread running in background: the thread is automatically handled via the standard library.

A promise allows to set a value once and to read from it as many times as needed. From a promise you can obtain as many futures as you like. It also allows more control on the result of the async computation, like sending back exceptions to the caller. [Here is an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/promise/set_exception/).

Remember to use locking or atomics whenever multiple threads read and writes to the same resources.

For completeness, a (stupid) example using futures:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex consoleLock;

void functionLongExecTime(int id) {
    int myints[] = {0,1,2};
    do {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << "id = " << id << " -- permutation: ";
        for (auto i : myints)
            ss << i << ' ';
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(consoleLock);
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    } while ( std::next_permutation(std::begin(myints), std::end(myints)) );
}

std::future<void> complexLogic(int id) {
    return std::async(&(functionLongExecTime), id);
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    // start 5 big computations
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        futures.push_back(complexLogic(i));
    }

    // do lots of stuff...
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "main awakes" << std::endl;

    // ensure that each computation finished
    for (auto &f : futures) {
        // if async computation finished, return immediately
        // otherwise, wait for async completion
        f.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of output:

```
id = 0 -- permutation: 0 1 2 
id = 0 -- permutation: 0 2 1 
id = 0 -- permutation: 1 0 2 
id = 0 -- permutation: 1 2 0 
id = 0 -- permutation: 2 0 1 
id = 0 -- permutation: 2 1 0 
id = 1 -- permutation: 0 1 2 
id = 1 -- permutation: 0 2 1 
id = 1 -- permutation: 1 0 2 
id = 1 -- permutation: 1 2 0 
id = 1 -- permutation: 2 0 1 
id = 2 -- permutation: 0 1 2 
id = 1 -- permutation: 2 1 0 
id = 2 -- permutation: 0 2 1 
id = 3 -- permutation: 0 1 2 
id = 2 -- permutation: 1 0 2 
id = 4 -- permutation: 0 1 2 
id = 3 -- permutation: 0 2 1 
id = 2 -- permutation: 1 2 0 
id = 4 -- permutation: 0 2 1 
id = 3 -- permutation: 1 0 2 
id = 2 -- permutation: 2 0 1 
id = 4 -- permutation: 1 0 2 
id = 3 -- permutation: 1 2 0 
id = 2 -- permutation: 2 1 0 
id = 4 -- permutation: 1 2 0 
id = 3 -- permutation: 2 0 1 
id = 3 -- permutation: 2 1 0 
id = 4 -- permutation: 2 0 1 
id = 4 -- permutation: 2 1 0 
main awakes
```

You can notice the overlapping of lines between async calls, showing the concurrency of the async computations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends the Thread class and has a string data member and a start method. From the WriteData function, you can then create a new thread and call the run method after passing std::string argument to the thread object. The run method will invoke the start(std::string) method in the Thread class.

Here is a prototype:

```
class MyThread : public Thread
{
    private:
    std::string s;
....
    public:
    setStr(std::string ss) { s = ss;}
    start() { ... }
....
}

main()
{
    class MyThread t;
    std::string ss = "Hello";
    t.setStr(
    t.run();
    ...
}
```